# vanilla javascript preview video file before upload - NO JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html

I have been searching for code to preview a video in client side before upload. I have seen MANY with Jquery. Personally i find external libraries bulky..... yet they rely on vanilla javascript to function (ironic..).
Previously, i found a page that describes this functionality. I can no longer find it.... so i am reaching out to the SO community. NOT asking for an application, or ready made code. looking for direction to tutorials/blogs that i can read to make this possible.
TY in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Within `change` event handler of `<input type="file">` element you can pass the `File` object to `URL.createObjectURL()` and set the `.src` of the `<video>` element to the resulting `Blob URL`.

```
document.querySelector("input[type=file]")
.onchange = function(event) {
  let file = event.target.files[0];
  let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  document.querySelector("video").src = blobURL;
}
```